# Comparing JPEG images with Javax ImageIO

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I am trying to compare 2 almost-identical documents stored as multiple image formats (.tif, .jpeg, .gif, .png, jpf) and mark visible differences with red color by comparing each pixel using Java ImageIO library with additional support plugin for jpeg2000 family.
Differences are quite simple - one document is identical to the other except for a single digit change in one of the lines, forming 2 documents differing in a single digit, but same format (png - png, jpeg - jpeg, ..). So far, I have used the following code, which is very straightforward - if `changeFile` differs in pixels from `baseFile`, mark the difference pixels from changeFile in the new image while persisting original `baseFile` pixels:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class ImageCompMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String baseFile = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Images/testA.jpg";
    String changeFile = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Images/testB.jpg";
    compareWithBaseImage(new File(baseFile), new File(changeFile), "Comparison_result");
  }
  public static void createComparisonImage(BufferedImage image, String fileExtension, String fileName)
      throws IOException {
    File out =  new File(fileName);
    ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension, new File(fileName));
    System.out.println("Path: " + out.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("width: " + image.getWidth());
    System.out.println("height: " + image.getHeight());
  }

  public static void compareWithBaseImage(File baseImage, File compareImage, String resultOfComparison)
    throws IOException {

    String filePath = baseImage.toPath().toString();
    String fileEnding = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath).toLowerCase();

    //reader needs "jpeg2000" as a parameter to process .jpf files, but the the file extension is .jpf
    String fileExtension = fileEnding.toLowerCase().equals("jpf") ? "jpeg2000" : fileEnding;
    String fileName = resultOfComparison + "." + fileEnding;
    BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(baseImage);
    BufferedImage cImage = ImageIO.read(compareImage);
    int height = bImage.getHeight();
    int width = bImage.getWidth();
    int imageType = fileEnding.toLowerCase().equals("jpf") ? BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
    System.out.println("imageType = " + imageType);

    BufferedImage rImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        try {
          int pixelC = cImage.getRGB(x, y);
          int pixelB = bImage.getRGB(x, y);
          if (pixelC == pixelB) {
            rImage.setRGB(x, y,  bImage.getRGB(x, y));
          } else {
            int a= 0xff |  bImage.getRGB(x, y)>>24 ,
              r= 0xff &  bImage.getRGB(x, y)>>16 ,
              g= 0x00 &  bImage.getRGB(x, y)>>8,
              b= 0x00 &  bImage.getRGB(x, y);

            int modifiedRGB=a<<24|r<<16|g<<8|b;
            rImage.setRGB(x,y,modifiedRGB);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // handled hieght or width mismatch
          rImage.setRGB(x, y, 0x80ff0000);
        }
      }
    }
    createComparisonImage(rImage, fileExtension, fileName);
  }
}
```

Probably due to compression occurring during storing a JPEG image, noise is generated around the symbol (marked in red color), which can be seen on the following image:
[image: JPEG-comparison]

Same difference when comparing .tif images is not there, and this is what I am aiming for in JPEG differences:
[image: TIFF-comparison]

As you can see, I am somewhat a newb when it comes to image processing, but also accepting the fact that JPEG is a lossy format and compression has its aftereffects. My questions is, is it possible to somehow eliminate the noise around the symbol in JPEG format?

Comment: If you know that your image is supposed to be two colors, then try reducing the color space to 1bit (with a well-chosen threshold) and you'll probably get cleaner difference. There might *still* be noise that's above the threshold, depending on how strongly compressed your images are, but it should be much less. Alternatively, switch the simple "is the color different" over to a "is the color different by more than some threshold value".

Comment: Unfortunately, there won't be only 2 colors, since official enterprise documents can have logos or some other objects that can be outside of black/white color schemes. If 2 colors were an option, I would probably go in direction of calculating pixel brightness, such as luminance, and based on some threshold or offset, preprocess the image to eliminate it, but I cannot.